add transitions to beamer overlays between slides
While working on a presentation, I wanted to add one of the few transitions in this work; however, for some reason, the before-and-after results in slide view seem to be the same. Essentially, I wish for image B to have some effect during transition between slide 1 and 2.
I believe I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure out exactly what is the issue... below a MWE. Also, I understand the code might not be optimal; I'm not very verse with LaTex yet, so any help is greatly appreciated.
P.S. don't worry about the cropping of image A, in the real slides it appears perfect using those values. Thanks again!
\documentclass[169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        {\begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill [color=bground] (0,0.868\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.1in}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle<1>{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: the workflow}
\frametitle<2>{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: the workflow}
\frametitle<3>{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: construction}
\frametitle<4>{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: mapping}
\frametitle<5>{Bringing together the graph and population \\ genetics: downstream analyses}
    
\only<3>{
\alert{Key contribution}: \dots
\vspace{-.24in}
            }
\only<4>{
\begin{flushleft}
\vspace{-.15in}
\alert{Key change}: \dots
\end{flushleft}
            }
\only<5>{
\begin{flushleft}
\alert{Key integration}: \dots
\end{flushleft}
            }

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max height=.75\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip<3> (-6,2)  rectangle (6,7);
\clip<4> (-6,-2.15)  rectangle (6,1.85);
\clip<5> (-6,-2.20)  rectangle (6,-7);
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\linewidth}
    \onslide<1->\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\column{.5\linewidth}
    \onslide<2>\transuncover\transduration{1}\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
\end{columns}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Don't use \onslide<1-> inside of the tikzpicture - it messes up your footline.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see, so is there a way to attain this same result with other approaches? Probably that will also allow for transitions to show up?

I don't have a pdf viewer which supports transitions, but you could try something like https://pastebin.com/0W1P5bWV

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks it's a very neat and effective solution; let me know how can I give you an upvote and approve the what you proposed!

Slide transition commands like \transpush are overlay aware. This means you can use something like \transpush<1-2> to specify which on which overlays they should be used:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.1in}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Bringing together the graph and population genetics:}
\framesubtitle<1-2>{The workflow}
\framesubtitle<3>{Construction}
\framesubtitle<4>{Mapping}
\framesubtitle<5>{Downstream analyses}
    
\transduration<1>{1}\transpush<2>  
    
\only<1-2>{\vfill}
\only<3>{\alert{Key contribution}: \dots}
\only<4>{\alert{Key change}: \dots}
\only<5>{\alert{Key integration}: \dots}

\begin{columns}<1-2>
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics<1-2>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics<2>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max height=.75\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip<3> (-6,2)  rectangle (6,7);
\clip<4> (-6,-2.15)  rectangle (6,1.85);
\clip<5> (-6,-2.20)  rectangle (6,-7);
\node<3-> at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

